# Cancel job within CircleCI workflow when another workflow with that job is triggered

Tags: circleci

Let's say we have a workflow called Workflow1 which contains jobs A, B, C and D.

First developer pushes a change and triggers Workflow1.

Second developer also pushes a change and triggers Workflow1.

Is there a way to ensure that when job C starts in the second developer's workflow, it automatically cancels only job C in the first developer's workflow, without affecting any of the other jobs?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement something using the [CircleCI API v2](https://circleci.com/docs/api/v2/index.html#circleci-api) and some [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) wizardry. Note: you'll need to create a [personal API token](https://circleci.com/docs/managing-api-tokens#creating-a-personal-api-token), and store it in an environment variable (let's call it `MyToken`)

I'm suggesting the below approach, but there could be another (maybe simpler ¯\_(ツ)_/¯) way.

1. Get the IDs of pipelines in the project that have the `created` status:

   ```
   PIPE_IDS=$(curl --header "Circle-Token: $MyToken" --request GET "https://circleci.com/api/v2/project/gh/$CIRCLE_PROJECT_USERNAME/$CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME/pipeline?branch=$CIRCLE_BRANCH"|jq -r '.items[]|select(.state == "created")')
   ```
2. Get the IDs of currently running/on_hold workflows with the name `Workflow1` **excluding the current workflow ID**:

   ```
   if [ ! -z "$PIPE_IDS" ]; then
     for PIPE_ID in $PIPE_IDS
     do curl --header "Circle-Token: $MyToken" --request GET "https://circleci.com/api/v2/pipeline/${PIPE_ID}/workflow"|jq -r --arg CIRCLE_WORKFLOW_ID "$CIRCLE_WORKFLOW_ID" '.items[]|select(.status == "on_hold" or .status == "running")|select(.name == "Workflow1")|select(.id != $CIRCLE_WORKFLOW_ID)|.id' >> currently_running_Workflow1s.txt
     done
   fi
   ```
3. Then (sorry, I'm getting a bit lazy here, and you also need to do some of the work :p), use the `currently_running_Workflow1s.txt` file generated above and the ["Get a workflow's jobs" endpoint](https://circleci.com/docs/api/v2/index.html#operation/listWorkflowJobs) to get the job number of each job in the related running `Workflow1` workflows whose name matches `job C` **and** that has a status `running`.
4. Finally, use the ["Cancel job" endpoint](https://circleci.com/docs/api/v2/index.html#operation/cancelJob) to cancel each of these jobs.

   *Note that there might be a slight delay between the "cancel API call" and the job actually being cancelled, so you might want to add
   a short `sleep`, or even better a `while` loop that [checks those
   jobs' respective statuses](https://circleci.com/docs/api/v2/index.html#operation/getJobDetails)*, before moving further.

I hope this helps.